# Cases with custom rule in Eisbach

Tags: isabelle

I wrote this rule:

```
method rule_inversion uses P = 
  (cases rule: nt_network[OF P])
```

but Isabelle tells me

```
Rule has fewer premises than arguments given
```

The exact `nt_network` doesn't seem to matter, since this fails the same way:

```
method rule_inversion uses R P = 
  (cases rule: R[OF P])
```

How do I apply `OF P` to a rule used for `cases` inside Eisbach when `P` is a parameter of the tactic?